# NSPredicate filter array but return only one field of an object

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nspredicate

I'm sure this question has been asked but I don't know what to search on.

I have array of Message objects with the following fields `{selected[BOOL], messageText[STR]}`. I want to filter this array to get only the objects with `selected=TRUE`. So far so good.

```
NSArray *messagesFiltered = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"selected == TRUE"]];
```

However, I don't need the objects themselves in the returned array, I need an array of the `messageText` strings. How to modify `predicate` to return only the `messageText` strings and not the whole object?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's not really the job of a predicate. Predicates are only for *filtering*, not *modifying*, the array you apply them to.

However, there's a fun little trick: the method [`-valueForKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCIBCDJ) will apply the kind of transform you want to your array. Just call it with the `messageText` key that you want:

```
NSArray *messagesFiltered = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"selected == TRUE"]];
NSArray *realMessages = [messagesFiltered valueForKey:@"messageText"];
```

On an array, `-valueForKey:` asks each element for a value for the given key, then returns an array of everything the elements returned. (Any element that returns `nil` for the key you pass shows up as `[NSNull null]` in the resulting array.)